# Warning message in disk utility

Tags: partitioning

After opening disk utility, I see an error message as follows on the 8.6G extended swap partition. "Warning: The partition is misaligned by 1024 bytes. This may result in very poor performance. Repartitioning is suggested." Should I be concerned? The only other partition is an 8.6G swap.  My OS is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8.6 GB swap? Do you really have > 8GB of RAM? Windows needs big swap space, but Linux only needs a swapspace equal to your RAM chip memory, unless you are editing humungous files.

As to repartitioning to fix the problem, use [gparted](http://gparted.org/) (and install it if you don't have it from [Synaptic](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) or Software Center) and resize the swap file, specifying Align To: ***Cylinder*** when you get to the [Resize screen](http://gparted.org/screens/gparted_5_big.png).

The only tricky thing about gparted is if you have multiple HDD/SSDs - look for the [spin box at right, above the middle](http://gparted.org/screens/gparted_4_small.png), which lets you select the drive to work on. If you only have one HDD or SSD then you need not worry about it.

Comment: kiloseven, thank you for your quick response. I do have 8GB of RAM, however I think the 8.6G extended swap I'm seeing is a partition on my HDD. After searching through the forum for similar problems I discovered this a common problem with Western Digital drives using Advanced Format. It seems your solution of using gparted is the way to go. A quick question, is gparted noob friendly? lol I hope so